# How to configure fastcgi with lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd, fastcgi

I am trying to configure FastCgi with ligttpd server.

I was able to run vanilla lighttpd like this:
./lighttpd -f lighttpd.conf

And then I compile/install the source of fastcgi, and I add the following in my lighttpd.conf:

```
fastcgi.server = ( "/fastcgi_scripts/" =>
      (( #"host" => "127.0.0.1",
         #"port" => 9091,
         "check-local" => "disable",
     "bin-path" => "/usr/local/bin/cgi-fcgi",
         "docroot" => "/" # remote server may use
                          # it's own docroot
      ))
    )
```

But lighttpd won't start after I add the above.

Can you please tell me how can I run fastcgi with lighttpd?
I want to use a c program with fastcgi with lighttpd.

Thank you.

Comment: Does it show any errors?

Answer (score 0):

This is all:

```
fastcgi.server = ( ".php" => ((
                     "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi",
                     "socket" => "/tmp/php.socket"
                 )))
```